# OutOfMemoryException with RestSharp file upload

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm implementing a simple file upload desktop tool with RestSharp. When I add a large file to the request with a custom stream writer (to update upload progress to the gui), `stream.Write` throws an OutOfMemoryException. Simplified code example:

```
...
var request = new RestRequest { Resource = "/test" };
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddFile("file", writer, "largefile.iso");

var response = client.Execute(request);
...

private void writer(Stream stream)
{
    using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead("d:\\download\\largefile.iso"))
    {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[16384]; //16k buffer
      int bytesRead = 0;
      int read = 0;

      while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        bytesRead += read;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("uploading: " + (int) ((double)bytesRead / reader.Length * 100) + "%");
      }
      reader.Close();
    }

}
```

This works fine with small files but Stream writing leaks memory, eventually crashing. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: There is a memory limit in .net. for 32 bit system, I think it is something like 2gb. If your file exceeds this memory limit, OutOfMemory exception is thrown. You may try to split file into smaller chunks and merge them again.

Comment: A couple side notes: 1) If you're using .NET 4 you should consider using [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) instead of rolling your own version. 2) I'm pretty sure `reader` will be closed for you when it is disposed by your `using` statement, so you shouldn't have to do it explicity.

Comment: The reason I'm using this is that I want to report progress from a background worker to the gui. Thats done instead of that debug in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this myself after digging RestSharp sources.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573

Comment: can you please clarify how you fixed this? I'm having the same issue that the uploading thread disappears after calling the RestClient Execute function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to flush the stream buffer after each write:

```
private void writer(Stream stream)
    {
        using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead("d:\\download\\largefile.iso"))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384]; //16k buffer
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int read = 0;

            while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                stream.Flush();
                bytesRead += read;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("uploading: " + (int)((double)bytesRead / reader.Length * 100) + "%");
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Flushing the stream didn't help. Tried that already... As I said the example works fine as long as filesize < mem available.